# Why do I need to write alert() after calling window.open()?

Tags: javascript

I have a page `index.jsp` available at this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/0smy7nlcmilkqt4/index.jsp.

This file contains a JavaScript method named `validateloginForm()` and is used to validate input fields.

If the fields are filled then it will redirect to another JSP page, but when I remove the `alert("after");` line below the `window.open()` line, then it does not redirect to another page.

Please let me know why I need to have this `alert("after")` after calling `window.open()`.

```
function validateloginForm()
{
    var empId = document.getElementById("empId").value;
    var empPass = document.getElementById("empPass").value;

    if( empId == "" )
    {
        alert("Enter id !");
    }
    else if( empPass == "" )
    {
        alert("Enter password !");
    }
    else
    {                 window.open("validateUser.jsp?"+"empId="+empId+"&empPass="+empPass,"_parent","",""); 
         alert("after");   
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the code after `window.open` is executed immediately and the window isn't loaded at that point.

Using `.alert` is only a coincidence, if you dismissed the alert before the window was loaded, it still wouldn't work.

```
var newwin = window.open("validateUser.jsp?"+"empId="+empId+"&empPass="+empPass,"_parent","",""); 
newwin.onload = function() {
    //do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser will not wait for the URL referenced by `window.open()` to load before returning. Without the `alert()`, therefore, your "validateloginForm" function will just return right away.

Generally things in the browser are **asynchronous**.  There's no way, in particular, to wait for `window.open()` to finish. You can have code in the page loaded into the new window call some function back on the parent ("opener") page, of course.

Comment: thanks to both of you ( Esailija and Pointy ) for explaining me this.