# Javascript - adding alert from if else function to new window on onclick

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, alert

So I have been working on this for a couple of days and as a newbie, I think the answer will really help my understanding of JavaScript.

I have a page that contains a form -- when a user submits the form a new window opens with form variables embedded within text in new window. It works fine.

The problem I am having is I want to add an alert to the new window if the user onClick types in NY || New York || NJ || New Jersey. I tested my if function (I left out the else after doing some research since else is really do nothing.

The way I want it to work is if someone types one of those four variables, a new window opens with the alert. If they don't type in one of those variables, only the new window opens.

I prepared a truncated test code which I'll put below. I know there are better ways to do this then the code I have written, and I bet there are probably easier ways with libraries, jquery, etc., but I would love for someone to show me how to add the askForHelp function so it will open the alert in the new window with code I have written. Again, that's b/c this is my knowledge base at this point, and it would help me see how to really write a statement. Thanks in advance for any help offered.

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>test</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">

       <script type="text/javascript">



   function newWindow() {
     allInfo= open("", "displayWindow");

   allInfo.document.open();

     allInfo.document.write('<!doctype html><html><head><title>Test</title><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>');
     allInfo.document.write(document.getElementById ('state').value);
     allInfo.document.write('<p>' + document.getElementById ('zip').value);
     allInfo.document.write('</section></body></html>');

     allInfo.document.close();
    }

   function askForHelp () {

   var volunteer = document.getElementById('state').value;

   if (volunteer == "New York" || "NY" || "New Jersey" || "NJ") { 
   allInfo.document.open.alert("test test test"); //Do I put the statement here?
  }  // else do nothing

    }
       </script>

      </head>

   <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>

     <form id="infoForm" method="post" name="infoForm">
      <p>State: </p>
      <p><input type="text" id="state" placeholder="State or Region"></p>

    <p>Zip: </p>
    <p><input type="text" id="zip" placeholder="Zip code" required /></p>


     <p><input type="button" value="Submit Information" onClick="newWindow(), askForHelp()" ></p> <!-- Should askForHelp() be here? -->
     </form>
      </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: I see a problem with this line `if (volunteer == "New York" || "NY" || "New Jersey" || "NJ")`  Instead do `if (["New York","NY","New Jersey", "NJ"].indexOf(volunteer)>-1)`. If that doesn't help, can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: @mheiber indexOf an array could be a problem on IE8 or less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 problems in your code:

1- You are trying to get a value for element with id=country and you don't have any element with id=country

```
allInfo.document.write('<p>' + document.getElementById ('country').value);
```

2- alert() function is attached to the window object not to the document object. So when you want to call the alert in the new window, you should call it like this:

```
allInfo.alert("blah blah");
```

3- The If condition in your code will always return true it should modified and be like this:

```
if((volunteer == "New York") || (volunteer =="NY") || (volunteer =="New Jersey") || (volunteer =="NJ"))
```

I have made the above modifications in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AvAH/). Please check it.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. The problem I saw with the jsFiddle was that the alert opened in the new window no matter what value I put for 'state'. The 'country' id was just an error in my code left over from original page. I'll try to edit that out.

Comment: Doh!. I didn't test this part out. Well I can clearly see that the conditions in the if statement will always result in true. If you want to make Or statements you should do it like this: `if((volunteer == "New York") || (volunteer =="NY") || (volunteer =="New Jersey") || (volunteer =="NJ"))`. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Wow. Thanks. This is it. It works. I just needed the allInfo.alert statement (and fixing the if statement with correct parentheses). I really appreciate it, and I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using JSFiddle, it won't let me put `document.write` but you can still how it works.. Check out this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nST7z/), below are the changes that I made..

HTML:

```
 <p><input type="button" id="submit-btn" value="Submit Information" ></p>
```

JS:

```
function newWindow() {
    alert("New Window");
}

function askForHelp () {
    var volunteer = document.getElementById('state').value;
    if (volunteer == "New York" || volunteer == "NY" || volunteer == "New Jersey" || volunteer == "NJ") { 
        alert("test test test");
    }
}
document.getElementById('submit-btn').addEventListener("click", function(){
    newWindow();
    askForHelp();
});
```

Comment: Thanks again, but I am still not getting it to work in the jsfiddle. The alert pops up without the new window no matter what values I put for state and zip. Maybe this is b/c the alert is called from newWindow? I still want the alert to come up in the new window only if one of the four values from the if statement is entered by the user.

Comment: "if someone types one of those four variables, a new window opens with the alert. If they don't type in one of those variables, only the new window opens", doesn't that conclude no matter what happens you want to `alert("new window");`, if user inputted those 4 values you will `alert("new window");` AND `alert("test test test");`.. That's what I made in the fiddle.. Please explain more about your goal.. Thanks

Comment: So what I actually want is for a new window to open with the submitted values written onto it unless a user types in one of those four values, then I want the new window to open with what the user submitted written onto it with an alert over it saying "test blah blah" Then when they click ok. They still see the new window with the values they submitted.

Comment: I had gotten it at one point (I don't even know how now) to open an alert when they submitted those values and for the new window to open with the values, but the alert was opening on the parent?? window.

Comment: I this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914076/why-do-i-need-to-write-alert-after-calling-window-open) is exactly what you are looking for, see how he use `.onload` in the new opened window.. I guess you can put your 'alert' inside that '.onload'.